# Distribution of Gauss sums on a circle in the Argand plane

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, gauss-sums

It is a fairly well-known fact that the [Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum) of a non-trivial character $\chi$ modulo a prime $p$ is always a complex number with an absolute value of $\sqrt{p}$.

In other words, when the Gauss sums of all non-trivial characters are plotted on the Argand plane, they must necessarily lie on the circle with radius $\sqrt{p}$ centered at the origin. Indeed, this is what is seen; however, the distribution of the Gauss sums on the circle is apparently random.

Is there a reason for this apparent randomness? Has the distribution of the Gauss sums on the circle of radius $\sqrt{p}$ been studied previously? Can one say no more about the Gauss sums, other than that they all have an absolute value of $\sqrt{p}$? Is it even reasonable to expect this distribution to have a pattern?

Here are some plots of the Gauss sums on the Argand plane, for $p = 23$ and $p = 7$:

[[image: Plot of the Gauss sums for <span class=]$p = 23$.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNbBF.png)

[[image: Plot of Gauss sums for <span class=]$p = 7$.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOzhJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ernst Kummer made a conjecture like the OP's, but it was disproven in 1978 by J. Patterson and R. Heath-Brown.  I found this in the article 'The determination of Gauss sums' by B. Berndt and R. Evans, which has a plethora of information.  If the prime gets large enough, then the distribution is uniform. Patterson even made a precise conjecture for the phenomena you have observed, a tendency for the roots to have positive real part.  (See formula at end of the paper's section 3.)